# Application for a long-term Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, long-stay-visas, schengen-visas

I just got a job in Germany, so now I am making my visa application. There are some fields which I am not sure. Please help me.
 1. In the application form: This form seems to be made for a short-term visa. What should I fill in "Intended date of departure" and "Intended duration of stay" ??? (my contract is unlimited and I don't have any plan to come back to my home town now) (UPDATED: just found out that the long-term visa form also has these sections).

2. In the long-term form: What should I answer these questions:

   - "Do you intend to maintain your permanent residence outside the Federal Republic of Germany?"
   - "Do you have health insurance that covers the Federal Republic of Germany?" ( I have no idea about it now, but I think I will buy one if I work in Germany, right?)

Thank you so much for your help.